# Fatal error has been detected by the JRE caused by connection method

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

My program is encountering a fatal error when executing this like a second time a loop executes this statement `Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();`.  What is causing this? Is it not allowed to pass a connection through a method? The program runs through this loop:

```
Connection conn = open_connection();

for(int aa = 0;aa<symbols.length;aa++){
    String[][] dub_array = parse(symbols[aa]);
    autowave(dub_array,19,14,symbols[aa],conn);
}
```

open_connection looks like this:

```
public static Connection open_connection() throws Exception{

    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String sDBQ = "C:/Documents and Settings/mike/Desktop/stock/data/AW.mdb";

    String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" + sDBQ + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=false";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( database ,"","");

    return conn;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x7c90100b, pid=3584, tid=8668
#
# JRE version: 7.0_02-b13
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (22.0-b10 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x100b]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Documents and Settings\mike\Desktop\stock\stock\hs_err_pid3584.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: are you using Vista/Windows 7?

Comment: It seems there is known issue with Vista/Windows. check this link if helpful http://java.com/en/download/help/exception_access.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My program is encountering a fatal error when executing this like a second time a
>   loop executes this statement Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
>      autowave(dub_array,19,14,symbols[aa],conn);
>   Try to create only one statement object before loop, then use it in loop. JdbcOdbcDriver with MS Access is lame and will meet unexpected issue sometimes.